# HookConsumerWidget in flutter causing dispose errors

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, dispose

In my flutter app, i use a list view inside a HookConsumerWidget, this list has a filter and once it filters the list tiles have big gaps, and i see this error:
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.

i couldn't solve it because its a HookConsumerWidget and its not flexible

Answer (score 0):

try to show some code snippets of the problem or the log messages,

my concern is when you're using HookConsumerWidget you don't need to use setState as you could manage the UI changes directly with listeners or watcher  with 'StateProvider' for example.